# Rspec/Rails test that a method has been called on an object within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, rspec, tdd

If I have the following code...

```
class Controller
  def create
    object = Foo.new
    object.bar("string")
  end
end
```

How might I rspec test that my `Foo` object received my `bar` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether your `Foo` object has reached your `bar` method or not, you need to verify whatever the `bar` method returns or does. If that verification passes, it means your `bar` method was reached and executed successfully.